# SQL Server 2012 Full Text Search Sproc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've got a number of tables in my database that have Full Text catalogues.  I've just created a new one and for some reason this one isn't working.

The Catalogue is created like this:

```
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG LicenseeName_catalog AS DEFAULT;
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Licensees
 ( 
  CompanyName Language 1033
 ) 
  KEY INDEX [PK_dbo.Licensees] ON LicenseeName_catalog WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
GO
```

And my stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LicenseeSearch] @inputterm NVARCHAR(256), 
                                       @includeNonSearchable BIT, 
                                       @skip INT, 
                                       @take INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @searchterm NVARCHAR(256)

SET @searchterm = '"' + @inputterm + '*"'
    SELECT * FROM 
        [dbo].[Licensees] lic
    WHERE CONTAINS(lic.*, @searchterm)
END
```

Obviously the Full Text stuff is installed correctly as my other catalogues are working as expected.  I've run full rebuilds of the index.  The weird thing is the catalogue creation and sprocs are more or less identical in terms of structure so why would one not work?

Unless I've made a mistake I've missed.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: "Not working" is a very short description of the problem...

Comment: It is but I just couldn't think of any way to get any more info about what the problem may be.  Adding test data and executing the sproc never returns anything yet all the t-SQL appears valid.

Comment: Execute the query manually with hard-coded search strings. Change the code to see where the problem is.

Comment: That's the first thing I did.  Gonna keep trying

Comment: If you can't make a manual query work, why are you debugging a procedure then? Solve the easy problem first. Please post the query plan. Try commenting out the full-text search `where` clause. Hard-code the search string as `'*'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LicenseeSearch] @inputterm NVARCHAR(256), 
                                       @includeNonSearchable BIT, 
                                       @skip INT, 
                                       @take INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


DECLARE @searchterm NVARCHAR(256);
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @searchterm = '"' + @inputterm + '*"'


SET @Sql=   'SELECT * FROM 
        [dbo].[Licensees] lic
    WHERE CONTAINS(lic.*,'''+ @searchterm +''')'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
END
```

Try this because when you pass @searchterm to you query it passes the parameter as "SomeValue*" where as query is expecting something like this '"SomeValue*"' this is where the devil dynamic sql comes in .

Comment: So how does the same syntax work in my other stored procedures?

Comment: @Jammer the way you are passing parameter it will pass the value for inputterm as "SomeValue*" , when you use dynamic sql it will pass the value as '"SomeValue*"' . Can you see the difference now ? Contains expects a value passed in single commas like 'your_Value', when you use SET searchterm = '"' + inputterm + '*"' it saves the values passed in the string but not the outer commas . In dynamic sql you add the commas in your sql statement and pass the parameters.

Comment: I've just tried using this and it doesn't work either.  The problem seems to be the full text catalogue.

Comment: OK its working.  I have a company called 'My New Company Ltd' and I was testing with a string of 'My*' which actually throws an error, as does 'My Company*' but 'Company*' works ... I have a lot to learn about FTS ...

Comment: One more thing when you are searching in more then one column in contains condition your column names should be in parenthesis something like CONTAINS((Col1, Col2), 'Some_Value');

Comment: @Jammer strange, that you could not reproduce this error with a hard-coded query. Anyway, this question was really about how to debug a problem with a query, not so much about the specific issue. Glad you got the problem fixed!